# What will happen to the lamp when the slide S moves in the indicated direction?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

[image]

Is the current in this this circuit going to flow through the metallic rod x, then through S, then finally through the metallic rod y? If so, then the parts of the rods x and y are connected in series as it appears to me and so by moving the slide in the indicated direction the total resistance increases, therefore decreasing the circuit current and reducing the power output of the lamp. Is my understanding right?

The rod x is of the same material as the rod y but the cross section of x is less than that of y, and S is made of copper.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Nope, it is not.